# MapInfo License Server - Can It Serve Multiple Versions of MapInfo

Tags: mapinfo, license

I have a MapInfo License Server Utility that serves 30+ MI v10.5 concurrent licenses across my organisation.

v11.5 has now landed on my desk (with new serial numbers and access codes), so can I activate my v11.5 licenses within the same instance of License Server utility, whilst retaining the v10.5 licenses, in order to gradually migrate users onto v11.5 over the coming months?

Comment: Thanks Peter, yes I am still using an old version of the LSU (v3.0) so need to upgrade to enable this. The trouble now is that LSU v3.6 is not supported on Windows Server 2003, but nobody suggests these things are ever easy.....

Answer (score 2):

Pitney Bowes Software recommends that you use the latest version of the MapInfo License Server Utility (LSU) with MapInfo Professional 11.5.

You'll find the latest version on your MI Pro disks or [on our web site](http://www.pbinsight.com/support/product-downloads/for/mapinfo-professional).

You can upgrade the LSU even when you have licenses activated. The upgrade procedure is described in the manual for the LSU.

And - to answer your question - you can have several versions of MapInfo Professional activated in the LSU at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

We have also had success running both versions at the same time.

The only thing we were concerned about was would each version be deemed as one serial number use or is there potential to run two versions with the same serial number?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! Something in you answer that I think needs clarifying is whether your question there is actually a statement and should be rearranged to remove its question mark, or is it a new question in which case it should be researched/asked separately.